# Batch script not sorting list correctly

Tags: batch-file

I made a batch script for a program called cpdf.exe to make my life a little easier but it doesn't really work.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set LIST=
for %%x in ("*.pdf") do set LIST=!LIST! "%%x"

for /F %%a in ('dir /b /o-n *.pdf') do set FileName=%%~na

cpdf.exe -merge %LIST:~1% -o %FileName%_Combined.pdf
```

When I run this, the resulting pdf comes out jumbled and not in numerical order. The pdf's I am inputting are prefixed with 01,02...ect..

I'm not sure what I need to make it list the files correctly to produce the PDF in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to run everything through just a single `For` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "LIST="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B /O-N *.pdf') Do (
    Set "LIST="%%A" !LIST!"
    Set "FileName=%%~nA"
)
CPDF.exe -merge %LIST% -o "%FileName%_Combined.pdf"
Pause
```

Comment: It didn't work, I think it's because there are spaces in the input pdf's filename.

Comment: @darkshaed, if there are spaces in the filenames, how is `-merge` supposed to know which strings in the list belong with each other? _You provided the command line, I've formulated my reply based on your information only!_

Comment: Not sure, I made this script a while ago, but in the original script I believe ("*.pdf") putting the quotes around was able to capture the entire filename. I tried to do the same in the script you provided but it didn't work. Not sure how to fix it.